# AngularJS, Promises and callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code (polling factory and controller):

```
app.factory('pollingService', ['$http', function($http){
    var defaultPollingTime = 3000;
    var polls = {};

    return {
        startPolling: function(name, url, pollingTime, callback) {
            // Check to make sure poller doesn't already exist
            if (!polls[name]) {
                var poller = function() {
                    $http.get(url).then(callback);
                }
                poller();
                polls[name] = setInterval(poller, pollingTime || defaultPollingTime);
            }
        },

        stopPolling: function(name) {
            clearInterval(polls[name]);
            delete polls[name];
        }
    }
}]);
```

And the following controller:

```
app.controller("dashboardController", function ($scope, pollingService){
    var serverBackendURL = "/json/testclass.php";
    $scope.getDashStats = pollingService.startPolling("dash", serverBackendURL, 3000, function(callback){
        return callback.data;
    });
        console.log($scope.getDashStats);
```

});

Naturally, $scope.getDashStats is undefined because -correct me if I'm wrong- startPolling returns a promise. I am quite new to angular, but I've googled a lot about promises and I think I've got the concept, but I don't know how to recode everything to make use of getDashStats. Any help?

Comment: You don't need to check `console.log($scope.getDashStats);` like that, this is asynch, it will always return `undefined`. You just need to ensure that your data is updated (another point in time) and angular js will update the view accordingly. See my answer for how to fix your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
pollingService.startPolling("dash", serverBackendURL, 3000, function(callback){
        $scope.getDashStats = callback.data;
 });
```

But I think you need this:

```
pollingService.startPolling("dash", serverBackendURL, 3000, function(data){
            $scope.getDashStats = data;
     });
```

Be aware that calling `console.log($scope.getDashStats);` will also display `undefined` because the response does not arrive yet. But whenever the data arrives, your `$scope.getDashStats` will be updated inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't return anywhere your poller promise that is the problem. If you don't specify the return according to ECMA specification JS returns undefined. So you need to return your promise object ($http.get(..) or make your own promise if you need and return)

Or you need just to assign the scope variable inside of the callback like this: pollingService.startPolling("dash", serverBackendURL, 3000, function(result){$scope.dashStats = result;}); And please don't name the result with the name similar to the function name. It confuses. Instead of getDashStats in this case better to use dashStats. getDashStats according to convention should be a function (but as far it is not promise it shouldn't)

Comment: would this one be correct?
        startPolling(name, url, pollingTime, callback) {
            // Check to make sure poller doesn't already exist
            if (!polls[name]) {
                var poller = function() {
                    $http.get(url).then(callback);
                }
                poller();
                polls[name] = setInterval(poller, pollingTime || defaultPollingTime);

                return poller;
            }

Comment: Just let me clarify - what getDashStats should return the promise or the actual data?

Comment: Ok. In this case misunderstood. You need just to assign the scope variable inside of the callback like this:

pollingService.startPolling("dash", serverBackendURL, 3000, function(result){$scope.dashStats = result;});

And please don't name the result with the name similar to the function name. It confuses. Instead of getDashStats in this case better to use dashStats. getDashStats according to convention should be a function (but as far it is not promise it shouldn't)